# Undefined symbols for architecture while editing Robovm bindings file

Tags: robovm

I'm trying to remove the AdColony SDK from the Mopub bindings, in order to achieve that I'm doing the following steps:

1. open `mopub.xcodeproj` on XCode.
2. delete the `AdColony folder` from the `AdNetwork Support Folder` and from the `Build Phases` Tab.
3. Rebuilding the project and copying the file `libmopub.a` under the `Debug-universal` Folder.
4. Adding `libmopub.a` to the bindings `libs` folder and to my project `libs` folder and update the `robovm.xml` file accordingly

When trying to build I get the following error:

**NOTE: Unmodified version of the `libmopub.a`works without any issues**

```
5/28/15 11:09:08 AM: [ERROR] Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
5/28/15 11:09:08 AM: [ERROR]   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MPLogProvider", referenced from:
5/28/15 11:09:08 AM: [ERROR]       objc-class-ref in libmopub.a(MPLogging.o)
5/28/15 11:09:08 AM: [ERROR]   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MPNativePositionSource", referenced from:
5/28/15 11:09:08 AM: [ERROR]       objc-class-ref in libmopub.a(MPInstanceProvider.o)
5/28/15 11:09:09 AM: [ERROR]   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MPGeolocationProvider", referenced from:
5/28/15 11:09:09 AM: [ERROR]       objc-class-ref in libmopub.a(MPCoreInstanceProvider.o)
5/28/15 11:09:09 AM: [ERROR]   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MPServerAdPositioning", referenced from:
5/28/15 11:09:09 AM: [ERROR]       objc-class-ref in libmopub.a(MPStreamAdPlacer.o)
5/28/15 11:09:09 AM: [ERROR]       objc-class-ref in libmopub.a(MPCollectionViewAdPlacer.o)
5/28/15 11:09:09 AM: [ERROR]       objc-class-ref in libmopub.a(MPTableViewAdPlacer.o)
5/28/15 11:09:09 AM: [ERROR]   "_kMoPubHTTPHeaderContentType", referenced from:
5/28/15 11:09:09 AM: [ERROR]       -[MPURLResolver stringEncodingFromContentType:] in libmopub.a(MPURLResolver.o)
5/28/15 11:09:09 AM: [ERROR]       -[MPURLResolver connection:didReceiveResponse:] in libmopub.a(MPURLResolver.o)
5/28/15 11:09:09 AM: [ERROR]       -[MRController connection:didReceiveResponse:] in libmopub.a(MRController.o)
5/28/15 11:09:09 AM: [ERROR]   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Chartboost", referenced from:
5/28/15 11:09:09 AM: [ERROR]       objc-class-ref in libmopub.a(ChartboostInterstitialCustomEvent.o)
5/28/15 11:09:09 AM: [ERROR]      (maybe you meant: _OBJC_CLASS_$_ChartboostInterstitialCustomEvent)
5/28/15 11:09:09 AM: [ERROR] ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
5/28/15 11:09:09 AM: [ERROR] clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
5/28/15 11:09:09 AM: [ERROR] Build failed
```